# Is it possible to get Drakconf in Ubuntu?

Tags: hardware, administration, system-settings

I am using PCLOS for a long time, but now considering to switch to Kubuntu due some unsolved issues in this distro and also because of much bigger applications choice in repositories.

However, essential issue for me is to have the Drakconf tools (also called Mandriva/Mageia/Pclinuxos Control Center) - some info is [here](http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/200906/page04.html).

I already tried many different distros but found nothing able tu fully replace this excellent and complex tool. Is there any possibility to get this also in Ubuntu?

thanks

PS: I think that at least beginner users would appreciate it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question the short way, yes.  But, Drakconf tools is part of the so-called drakxtools and is specifically designed for Mandriva. However if the source code is available, it can be ported to other distributions.

The Ubuntu System Settings allows you to configure various parts of your system using a collection of tools.

[image]